# Manage permissions on docker openLDAP

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I want to change some permissions of my openLDAP instance running on Docker (https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap).

- Forbid anonymous login (forbid even read-only)
- Give any user who is not an admin no read-access to anything except himself
- A user should only be able to change his own password

I figured out that this kind of permission managing is done via ACL (Access Control Lists).

**But where can I create these ACL (or edit the existing ones) in docker-openLDAP?**

I would be very glad if you have a solution to this, im rather stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

As a dn with the appropriate privileges (probably whatever admin the container had you setup), you should be able to run an `ldapmodify` with the following ldif.

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to *
  by group.exact="cn=ldap-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by * break
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword
  by self write
  by * auth
olcAccess: {7}to *
  by * none
```

I don't know if the docker image uses `olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config` so the dn to modify might be something else. You should be able to query for the relevant olcSuffix.